# How can I restrict a user permission to contribute in only one repository in AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I wanted to restrict a user to only one repository in AzureDevOps, the user has basic permissions at the project level. I have also given the user contribute access to that specific repository. The user is not part of any other group.

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I restrict a user permission to contribute in only one
> repository in AzureDevOps

We can go `Project Settings=>Repositories=>choose repos you want to protect`, search the user you want to limit, and deny the `Contribute-related` permissions one by one:

[image]

[image]

We can even deny the `Read` permission so that the user can't view specific repos. Here's [a blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-devops-setting-up-repository-permissions/) for this topic.

PS: If you have 5 repos(A.B.C.D.E) and you want to restrict the user to only one repository(C), you have to set the permissions for A,B,D,E one by one.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict user access to specific Repo, there are many ways. Irrespective user has Basic access at the Org level he/she must be part of the project role to access repo. By default below roles have access to all repo across projects
[image]

Hence either add a user to any other role from the above list and add that role to that particular repository permissions

Another option is to create a custom role and the user to that role and add a role to repository permission.

Or if the user is not part of the above roles, the user can also be given repo access directly

Method
Go to Project >> Project settings(at bottom left corner) >> go to repository settings as below
[image]

[image]

In the search box enter username and add the user